# MySQL Workbench Ground To A Virtual Halt

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have been using MySQL Workbench for a while for both backups and to develop a database and associated queries. Over that time I have noticed that it slows noticeably if the SQL Editor has to many tabs (20 or over) and have tried to keep to a maximum of a dozen. However I came in this morning to find on start up there were approximately 150 tabs! 30% are the same query! In the midst of this are a few complex queries that I need to copy and save which means I do not want to reinstall at the moment. The problem is that it is taking up to ten minutes to access and close some of the tabs so it could potentially take days to sort out. Is there a back door into these?

Also what I cannot understand is why the tabs self replicated themselves?

As I have worked through Workbench has sped up and is now averaging under five minutes per tab! Only data entry can be more boring!

Comment: I finally got through all the tabs at 7:00 pm and recovered the few complex queries I needed - now documented and backed up on a server. Workbench still seemed sluggish but improved dramatically after a reinstall. It seems that there is a lurking bug in Version 5.2.38 but how do I avoid it happening again?

Comment: You have outgrown Workbench.  It is time to build your application using something more powerful and faster -- PHP / Java / VB / ...

Comment: At the moment the database is quite small in my opinion. There are approximately 2000 basic patient records (name, gender, address, etc), a similar number with details such as BMI and ~250 test requests and their associated results (X-ray, blood count, etc.). MySQL Workbench is used more in the background as the main app is written in Python, wxPython and SQL.